# PHP extract comparison operator

Tags: php

I was asked on an interview what would be the fastest way to extract the comparison operator between two statements.

For example `rate>=4` the comparison operator is '>=' it should be able to extract `'>','<','!=','=','<=','>=','='`

The function must return the comparison operator.

This is what I wrote, and they marked it as wrong.

```
  function extractcomp($str)
    {
       $temp = [];
       $matches = array('>','<','!','=');
       foreach($matches as $match)
       {
           if(strpos($str,$match)!== false)
            {

               $temp[] = $match; 
            }
       }

       return implode('',$temp);

    }
```

Does anyone have a better way?

Comment: What other limits where there? Was any function allowed?

Comment: it was supposed to run as fast as possible o(n) even though i find micro-optimizations from string manipulation completely stupid.

Comment: From what I can see your method is slower than a normal regex: https://3v4l.org/dse0c/perf#output vs https://3v4l.org/0hhRC/perf#output . And you could have skipped the temp array and just made it a string you append. That way implode is not needed

Comment: according to those results mine is compiling faster

Comment: Walk away from the interview.

Comment: This should be a CodeReview question, shouldn't it?  I mean, there is no error to fix in your code.  Dear high-reppers/moderators, how does migration work?

Comment: Not related to the question, but `=` is not a [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). It is an [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

Comment: @Edward here is a comparison. And you are right sometimes your looping does perform better and sometimes regex runs faster with the exact same input. Odd that it changes like that. I added *1000 to not get scientific numbers as outputs. https://3v4l.org/03u46

Comment: @Andreas Again, if you are going to run a fair comparison of regex vs non-regex, you should give `preg_match()` an optimized pattern like:  `/[<>!]=?|=/`  (this is the same pattern logic with 15 steps vs 39 steps)

Answer (score 2):

you can read character by character once you hit the first occurrence you can determine what's gonna be the next character i.e.:

```
$ops = ['>','<','!','='];
$str = "rate!=4";
foreach($ops as $op)
{
    if(($c1 = strpos($str, $op)) !== false)
    {
        $c2 = $str[$c1++] . (($str[$c1] == $ops[3]) ? $str[$c1] : "");
        break;
    }
}
echo $c2;
```

So if the first search character is ">" you can only assume the 2nd one is gonna be "=" or it doesn't exist. So you get the index of 1st character and increment it and check if the 2nd character exists in our search array or not. Then return the value. this will loop until it finds the 1st occurrence then breaks.

EDIT:
here's another solution:

```
$str = "rate!=4";
$arr = array_intersect(str_split($str), ['>','<','=','!']);
echo current($arr).(end($arr) ? end($arr) : '');
```

not as fast as the loop but definitely decreases the bloat code.

There's always a better way to optimize the code.

Comment: +1 This is a solid loop answer. I've written up an [equivalent code using a custom function](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da76ff241470591526ba3f72e3d657ca5ce44335).  I replaced your break with return.  As micro-improvements (I mean super-micro), I used pre-incrementation instead of post-incrementation, and used strict check for trailing `=` instead of loose. (for the record, still not quite as fast as trim)

Comment: @mickmackusa - there's always a better way to do things. but let's say if they require you to write something and not to use a "ready-to-use" function and that's what most of the interviews ask, they wanna see how you think about the logic instead of the final result. Also this can be customized based on your needs while the trim function doesn't provide that.

Comment: You are right, the employer may be looking for design logic.  The employer may also be interested in discovering the breadth of function vocabulary and a candidate's ability to think outside of the box and use less obvious approaches (we won't know).  My method does have greater vulnerability to breaking due to a value on either side of the operator containing an operator symbol.  Your patterns are less vulnerable -- they are only broken when an operator symbol occurs on the left side. (well, if you use `next()` instead of `end()` then the second method will work as the first)

Answer (score 1):

Unless they have some monkeywrenching strings to throw at this custom function, I recommend [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) with a ranged character mask.  Something like `echo trim('rate>=4',"A..Za..z0..9");` would work for your sample input in roughly half the time.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gPdIV/perf#output))

```
function extractcomp($str){
    return trim($str,"A..Za..z0..9");
}
echo extractcomp("rate>=4");
```

---

Regarding regex, better efficiency in terms of step count with `preg_match()` would be to use a character class to match the operators.

Assuming only valid operators will be used, you can use `/[><!=]+/` or if you want to tighen up length `/[><!=]{1,3}/`

Just 8 steps on your sample input string. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/m1FxyB/1)

This is less strict than Andreas' `|` based pattern, but takes fewer steps.

It depends on how strict the pattern must be.  My pattern will match `!==`.

---

If you want to improve your loop method, write a `break` after you have matched the entire comparison operator.

Actually, you are looping the operators.  That would have been their issue (or one of them).  Your method will not match `==`.  I'm not sure if that is a possible comparison (it is not in your list).

Comment: fair point on the '==' but that wasn't in the comparison array

Comment: @Andreas I did.  Twice now.  If you are going to pit `preg_match()` against a non-regex method.  The fairest thing would be to use the fastest pattern, right?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. I have not got you banned. You did that. Not me. I did not use your account and post with your name. You did that. I have not downvoted this as you can see from the image. I really don't understand your problems. It seems you keep blaming everything on everyone else.

Comment: @Andreas then you have my apology.